# jshint and sass/scss not working with Webpack 2.2

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, jshint

`/Website`

---`/Scripts/*.js`

---`/sass/*.scss`

---`/dist/*.css`

I want to do 2 things :

- JShint the .js files
- Compile the scss file and move them to dist folder

I tried this configuration, but it does't seem to work.

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require("path"),
    glob = require("glob"),
    jshint = require('jshint-loader'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync("./Scripts/**/*.js"),
    output: {
        path: "./Scripts/",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "jshint-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".css", ".sass", "scss"]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./dist/[name].css')
    ]
}
```

When I run webpack, the .js files are bundled into a `main.js` file and errors are emitted.

1. What am I missing to be able to JSHint the .js files
2. Is it possible to tell webpack to not bundle the files and just execute the JSHint
3. Why Im not getting the css files